# React Native: CLI fails to install app on android emulator

Tags: android, linux, react-native

A few months ago, I started a react-native project on my windows pc. At some point, I pushed it all to my github repository, and intended to continue working on it on my linux laptop. However, it never worked on my linux system.

### The Issue

When running `npm run android`, the installation of the app on my android emulator fails. However, that is only the case when executing it on my project repository. If I use `npx react-native init ALT_PROJECT` to setup a new react-native project, and run the command there, it works without issue.

### Things I have verified / already tested

- My code has no issues, as copying all the code files to a new react-native project does not hinder `npm run android` in installing the app.
- Updating react-native from 0.72.5 -> 0.73.2 did not change anything
- Running `chmod 755 android/gradlew` allowed for installation to start, but it still fails. Error changed from

```
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with EACCES: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
spawn ./gradlew EACCES.
```

to

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: file:///home/oliver/Documents/Coding/testTodoApp2/alt/frontend/project/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt:391:46 Unresolved reference: attr

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 57s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: file:///home/oliver/Documents/Coding/testTodoApp2/alt/frontend/project/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt:391:46 Unresolved reference: attr FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

- Making sure `$ANDROID_HOME` is set
- Making sure `$PATH` includes `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` and `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
- Running `npx react-native doctor` gives me only a single error, that Android Studio couldn't be found. I have, however, read that that always happens when Android Studio hasn't been installed in the default directory, and that it does not affect functionality (Since I DO have Android Studio installed)

### Tech Details

- OS: Linux Mint 20.3

Please help me out, I have sunk a dozen hours into this specific problem, and I just don't know how to continue. Tell me if you need more information. Thank you.